# Why @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) produces Duplicate Key exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, annotations, entity

I inherited an implementation that throws :

```
ava.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key
```

when I am processing the results of the JPA call.

My Entity code is :

```
public class JobMetadataEntity implements Serializable {

    // This field is NOT a DB Column
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "MODULE")
    private String module;
```

My Repository code :

```
List<JobMetadataEntity> findAllByModule(String module);
```

Application code that throws an Exception :

```
   Map<Integer, JobMetadataEntity> jobMetadataEntityMap = jobMetadataRepository.findAllByModule("MODULE_NAME")
                        .stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getId(), e -> e));
```

My understanding the problem is with with adding an element to the Map :

```
Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getId(), e -> e)
```

Somehow the generated  "key" is a duplicate. This code is being called multiple times and on  a few occasions it throws an Exception. My SpringBoot version is 2.7.6

Comment: This question is because your query is returning entities in the result that have the same id value. You need to look at how the findAllByModule actually translates to SQL, but it can easily return the same entity multiple times if there are joins over any  *toMany relationships. Look at the entity relationships, turn on SQL logging and it should be clear what and why it is happening. You can also workaround the issue by querying with 'DISTINCT' on the entity: "Select distinct e from JobMetadataEntity e where e.module = :module" which should have your JPA provider account for joins

Comment: findAllByModule returns all the Fields from the underlying table defined in Entity class. And there are no any conditions in the query except "module = <passedParameter>". And an ID field is not coming from the DB, there is NO ID column. My understanding every returned Entity must have new and unique ID.

Comment: If your entity does not have any references (and the SQL doesn't have joins to other tables), then the issue is entirely in what the getId is returning - Your Collectors.toMap requires that each of these instances return a unique value from the getId method. If there is no id column, where is your getId value coming from? The query should fail as the SQL must be trying to select ID From the table, which you state doesn't exist. So what is it executing and what is it returning?

Comment: Also note, GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) requires the column to exist in the database. JPA will insert the entity, the database will then auto generate the column value, and JPA will lookup the value that was used to set it in the managed entity (so it can be indexed/cached on the value). The property marked as the ID within JPA must be unique, but it is on you, the application developer, to ensure it is so. There is no magic within JPA that ensures it- you can absolutely create tables that allow rows with duplicate data in them or mark some non-unique property as the ID.